# Step Functions calling an Operation/API of a fargate service deployed in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions, amazon-ecr

I have a service deployed in ECS as a Fargate service. Eg. BookService with GetBooks & PutBooks operations to add and get the book details.

I am trying to call GetBooks & PutBooks operations in ECS from a Step function. Is it possible? Any reference will be very helpful.

[StepFunction] -> [ECS - Fargate]

Default Step function to call ECS task

```
 "Manage ECS task": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
    "Cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/MyECSCluster",
    "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:1222333:task-definition/booksPocEcsServiceTaskDef:4"
  },
  "End": true
}
```

Comment: I am currently introducing a lambda to invoke the ECS from the Step Function. Looks like AWS doesn't support calling the API through StepFunction. However, a task can be invoked by passing the environment variables. But, my use-case is not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step Functions can only call ECS RunTask with it's built in integration. If you're trying to call a web service running on Fargate, Step Functions doesn't currently support arbitrary HTTP requests.

You could front your Fargate service with API Gateway, which Step Functions can invoke directly. Another alternative is using a Lambda function to call your service, as you've already done.